# Flux that can be represented by low and high resolution schemes

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde, numerical-integration

In the wiki page of [Flux limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_limiter), it writes:

> If these edge fluxes can be represented by low and high resolution schemes, then a flux limiter can switch between these schemes depending upon the gradients close to the particular cell, as follows,
> $$ F\left(u_{i+{\frac {1}{2}}}\right)=f_{i+{\frac {1}{2}}}^{low}-\phi \left(r_{i}\right)\left(f_{i+{\frac {1}{2}}}^{low}-f_{i+{\frac {1}{2}}}^{high}\right),\\{\displaystyle F\left(u_{i-{\frac {1}{2}}}\right)=f_{i-{\frac {1}{2}}}^{low}-\phi \left(r_{i-1}\right)\left(f_{i-{\frac {1}{2}}}^{low}-f_{i-{\frac {1}{2}}}^{high}\right)},\\\\$$
> where $f^{{low}}=$ low resolution flux,
> $f^{{high}}=$ high resolution flux,
> $ \phi(r)=$flux limiter function,$r_{{i}}={\frac  {u_{{i}}-u_{{i-1}}}{u_{{i+1}}-u_{{i}}}}.$

I'm new to this area, my question is, what is the definition of low resolution schemes? I can only find definition about high resolution schemes. Most importantly, how do we know if a flux can be represented by low and high resolution schemes? If it can, then what are the explicit expressions of $f^{low}$ and $f^{high}$? For example, the Godunov flux is $$f^{God}(u_l,u_r):=\begin{cases}\max_{u\in[u_l,u_r]}f(u)~~\text{if }u_l> u_r\\\min_{u\in[u_r,u_l]}f(u)~~\text{if }u_l\le u_r\end{cases},$$
given that $f$ is convex, then can it be represented by low and high resolution schemes? What about other fluxes such as the Lax-Friedrichs flux or the Engquist-Osher flux? Many thanks advance!

Comment: This isn't a research question, so it's probably not appropriate for MO.  You could ask on scicomp.SE.  But if you're new to the area and want to learn more, I recommend starting with [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-8629-1) or [this book](http://depts.washington.edu/clawpack/book.html).